# Microsoft Bot Framework Unauthorized error

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, botframework, chatbot

I am getting started with the Microsoft Bot Framework, and tried running the very basic app from the getting started tutorial using the emulator.
When I send the message, I get the error : 401 Unauthorized

**Things I have done**

I have corrected the URL in the emulator to match the correct URL of the app.
Have deleted the APP ID and APP password from the emulator fields.

I assume I don't need to worry about https yet, since I am running locally (localhost).

Comment: Did you add your app id and app password?

Comment: @codelahiru : In web.config? Yes.

Comment: Are you running that in localhost?

Comment: Try adding your app id and pass to emulator

Comment: @codelahiru : wow.. that works :). But the documentation tells just the opposite. Happy to mark it as an answer, if you post it down

Comment: Good to hear that. I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft Bot Framework Document says that when you're running in the `localhost` add your `localhost` with the correct port and ask you to keep empty in the app id and the app pass.

[image]

But if you have added you your app id and and pass to `web.config` file, make sure to add them to your emulator as well. Otherwise you will get `401 - Unauthorized` error.